# Split audio route in active VoiceChat AVAudioSession to play at AirPlay but record using a device

Tags: ios, iphone, avaudiosession, airplay, videochat

I'm building a video chat app for iPhone.
One of the requirements that it should work fine with `AirPlay`.
Once I'm switching to `AirPlay` the video goes to the `AppleTV` but audio stays on the phone. The resulting audio route is `Speaker-and-EmbeddedMic` and I don't see an option to switch the audio route to `AppleTV (AirPlay)` and continue to record using the mic.

`VideoChat` mode is NOT active - I could play audio using `AppleTV` (AirPlay):
[image]

`VideoChat` mode IS active - I have two output devices now - speaker & earpiece:
[image]

- Is it possible to use output `PlayAndRecord` session with `VideoChat`
  mode enabled?
- What is the possible solution for that?